# How to prevent user to change the profile by set current button in AutoCAD?

Tags: c#, autocad

I have a WPF application and i am opening a drawing in AutoCAD from my application. I just wanted to restrict user to change current profile using set current button, and i didn't want to make profile changes in registry settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find the answer finally, Just use UrrentProfileChangingEventHandler to show a popup and on CurrentProfileChangedEventHandler event make profile active which you want. Here is the code.

Put on initialize method

```
UserConfigurationManager bnb = Autodesk.AutoCAD.ApplicationServices.Core.Application.UserConfigurationManager;

            bnb.CurrentProfileChanging += UserConfigManagerEvent_CurrentProfileChanging_Handler;

            bnb.CurrentProfileChanged += UserConfigManagerEvent_CurrentProfileChanged_Handler;
```

Add method which is call on profile changing event

```
private void UserConfigManagerEvent_CurrentProfileChanging_Handler(object sender,ProfileEventArgs e)
        {
            string profileName = acApp.GetSystemVariable("CPROFILE").ToString();
            curProfile = e.ProfileName;
            if (profileName != curProfile && !IsMessageDisplayed)
            {
                IsMessageDisplayed = true;
                MessageBox.Show("The selected profile is not associated with Project");
            }

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(prevProfile))
            {
                prevProfile = profileName;
            }
        }
```

Call after profile change event

```
private void UserConfigManagerEvent_CurrentProfileChanged_Handler(object sender, ProfileEventArgs e)
        {
            AcadApplication app = (AcadApplication)Application.AcadApplication;
            AcadPreferences pref = app.Preferences;
            string cur = curProfile;
            if (curProfile.Equals(prevProfile))
            {
                IsMessageDisplayed = false;
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                pref.Profiles.ActiveProfile = prevProfile;
            }
        }
```